# Variation on the classic Boy - Girl Probability Problem

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics

Revisiting the pair Boy-Girl probability question that I got asked during an interview ~6 months ago.

1. The first question is similar to the classic "if the family has 2 children and 1 girl, what is the probability the 2nd child is a also a girl", however, I specifically asked the interviewer if we could assume that we know that a daughter came first
2. The follow up question is what stumped me - repeat the question above, however, assume the probability of having a girl is now 2/3.

For the first question, I answered 1/2. However, I wasn't expecting a follow-up so I believe I just overthought the 2nd question in the heat of the interview.. but the answer I came up with was 2/3. Wondering if I got the right answer here (evidently messed up somewhere, I didn't get the job)

Answer (score 0):

The question is kind of ambiguous, I think it appears as a problem in David Mackay's classic inference text. Anyway, let me rephrase your question as **"If the number of girls among the children is greater than 1, what is the probability that both children are girls."** I think this is what the question intends.

This is a straightforward application of conditional probability if we clearly define our events. We let the marginal probability of having a girl be denoted by $p$.

$$ P(\# G = 2 \vert \# G \geq 1) = \frac{P(\#G = 2, \#G \geq 1)}{P(\# G \geq 1)}$$

The two events $(\#G = 2, \#G \geq 1)$ are already contained in the event $\#G = 2$, so the numerator is just $p(\# G = 2) = p^2$.

The event $\#G \geq 1$ is the complement of the event of having no female children, so $p(\#G \geq 1) = 1 - p(\#G = 0) = 1 - (1-p)^2 $. So this simplifies to:

$$ P(\# G = 2 \vert \# G \geq 1) = \frac{p}{2 - p}$$.

So for the first case assuming equal prior probabilities $p=1/2$ and the answer is $1/3$, but for the second case you're given $p=2/3$ and $ P(\# G = 2 \vert \# G \geq 1) = 1/2$.

Comment: But doesn't our answer change given that we know that the first child is already a girl? I agree with your answers given we don't know anything else about the children other than  that at least 1 is a girl.. but I would think that the additional knowledge would change our answer to both scenarios?